# @Version field in entity class not increased during JPA test even though I updated it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple Repository:

```
public interface ReviewRepository extends CrudRepository<ReviewEntity, Integer> {

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  List<ReviewEntity> findByProductId(int productId);
}
```

I want to test it using test containers I followed the procedures and wrote my test case:

```
public abstract class MySqlTestBase {
  private static MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer("mysql:5.7.32");

  static {
    database.start();
  }

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void databaseProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", database::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", database::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", database::getPassword);
  }

}



@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class PersistTests extends MySqlTestBase {

  @Autowired
  private ReviewRepository repository;

  private ReviewEntity savedEntity;

  @BeforeEach
  void setupDb() {
    repository.deleteAll();

    ReviewEntity entity = new ReviewEntity(1, 2, "author1");
    savedEntity = repository.save(entity);
    assertEqualsReview(entity, savedEntity);
  }

  @Test
  void update() {
    savedEntity.setAuthor("author2");
    repository.save(savedEntity);



       ReviewEntity foundEntity = repository.findById(savedEntity.getId()).get();
       assertEquals(1, (long)foundEntity.getVersion());
       assertEquals("author2", foundEntity.getAuthor());
          }
    }
```

my ReviewEntity also is written like:

```
@Entity
public class ReviewEntity {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Version
  private int version;

  private int productId;
  private int reviewId;
  private String author;

  public ReviewEntity(int productId, int reviewId, String author) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.reviewId = reviewId;
        this.author = author;
}

          // setter and getter
    
    }
```

When I run this test it fails at the `assertEquals(1, (long)foundEntity.getVersion());` line with this message:

```
expected: <1> but was: <0>
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

But I update the `ReviewEntity` class and according to the documentation the `@Version` field should automatically increases but this not happens. what part of my test is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the default implementation of `save` method in `CrudRepository` interface in the `SimpleJpaRepository` class you will see `save` method is implemented like:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

    Assert.notNull(entities, "Entities must not be null!");

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

meaning it is marked with `@Transactional` with `Required` as its propagation level(it is default)

[Required](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation#1-required-propagation) propagation works like this:

> REQUIRED is the default propagation. Spring checks if there is an
> active transaction, and if nothing exists, it creates a new one.
> Otherwise, the business logic appends to the currently active
> transaction

and for `DataJpaTest` annotation comment section says:

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and
> roll back at the end of each test

So for method `update` in your test a transaction is going to be created and the save method in `repository.save(savedEntity);` is going to be appended to that transaction. meaning it is committed only if that transaction successfully committed and we now know that's not going to happen.

A workaround for this problem **probably** would be to annotate test class with `@Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED)` to suspends the currently running transaction then for `repository.save(savedEntity);` a transaction is going to be created and committed at the end of `save` method and then you can proceed in your test.